# How to open a webpage on a local computer outside of its hosted RDP connection?

Tags: c#, windows, rdp

I would like to know if there is a technique or solution for the follow problem.

I have a software application that is currently running inside of a Microsoft RDP session. I have some help resources built into it in which some of them open up on a webbrowser. Some of them are YouTube videos. The problem is taht through organisational policies, they cannot open YouTube clips within the RDP which connects to a interstate server.

What I would like to do is instead open up a webpage outside of that RDP connection on the local host computer instead, which does not have any restrictions like opening up YouTube webpage to play video clips.

Can you please suggest a technique, utility or solution to this problem?

Thanks,

Colin.

Comment: You could put a specially formatted link on the clipboard, and have a program running locally that detects this link and opens YouTube (provided the clipboard is shared across the connection). If it were actually possible for an RDP session to trigger commands on the connection computer directly, this would be a major security issue.

Answer (score 1):

The nicest way to do this would probably be to create a dynamic virtual channel plugin for RDP: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540859(v=vs.85).aspx

You would have a server-side component registered to handle the protocols (http/https, I assume) you want to redirect back to the client, possibly with some filtering logic if you still want a few to run server-side (such as intranet sites); then a client-side mstsc plugin whose only job is to call ShellExecute on the URLs you pass back.

Piggybacking on clipboard redirection might be less code, but it obviously has side-effects - e.g it obliterates anything else the user might have had on the clipboard.